# Connection of two identical transformers

Tags: transformer

I have a substation with two identical transformers 110kv/25kv single phase 50 hz usually one acts as spare. Now for some reason i want to charge my substation from secondary side i.e., 25 kv side from one of the transformer. Let us say My voltage at secondary side is 21 KV, corresponding voltage at primary side will be 120 KV (SAY). Now i want to feed this 120 kv to the primary of second transformer duly keeping the different tap at secondary of second transformer so that out put voltage of second transformer is maintained at 25 KV. Is this arrangement possible? .

Comment: Sorry, but your numbers don't add up, and you aren't being clear in what you are asking.  I am not inclined to even answer if I was sure of your question, as playing around with a 110KV substation isn't casual business.  I know what happens when they fault.

Comment: If in the kV range you have to come here and ask this kind of questions, you are clearly not in a position to play with kV ranges, no matter how good any answer here will be.

Answer (score 2):

There is no physical reason you can't back-energise your 110 kV (HV) system from 25 kV (LV). However, watch out for the following issues:

- Protection settings do not usually expect reverse power flow, or back-energisation. You may find that the LV protection trips on reverse power or directional overcurrent, or the LV overcurrent protection trips on magnetising inrush current.
- Any power transmitted from 120 kV -> 25 kV -> 120kV will suffer two lots of voltage drop. You can compensate for this using the transformer's tap-changers.

If you do not understand the above, this indicates that you should not be working on HV equipment, unless closely supervised by someone who does understand the above.

More so than usual for my other posts, this is **not professional engineering advice**. In case of doubt, consult a professional engineer who is familiar with your installation to provide detailed advice.

**Do not mess with HV equipment** unless you have been trained, deemed competent, and authorised by the owner/operator of the equipment. **Do not perform HV switching** unless your switching sheet has been checked and authorised by a person who is familiar with the equipment, and trained, deemed competent, and authorised by the person taking charge of electrical works.

You will **kill someone** if you do not know what you are doing.